# Single word for "time of the day"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for *time of the day*?

A collective expression for morning, afternoon, evening, etc.

---

An example I can think of to better explain what I'm looking for:

> Good **____**! - Insert the correct time/part of the day here to greet someone at 11 AM.

In the above sentence, I would like to replace "time/part of the day" with a single word.

Comment: @Mynamite In your opinion, `day` is synonym with `time of the day`?

Comment: @LordZsolt, this question has been asked and answered before (so don't get upset if this question is closed as a duplicate), though personally I find the answers unsatisfactory. In short, you've got "**hour**" (an *hour of the day* can refer to more than a 60 minute period, eg the Catholic canonical hours include *lauds*, *vespers*, and *compline*),  "**period**" (which is the the word you'd find used if you looked up *morning*, *evening* etc), **daypart** (jargon in broadcasting), **watch** (on a ship), **salat** (in Islam, if I understand correctly), but no proper hypernym for morning, etc.

Comment: 'Day' can mean several things, it's easy to look them up. 24 hours; day as opposed to night; day as an era ("In my day we used to etc"). What do you mean by 'time of the day'? Morning, afternoon and evening are parts of a day, therefore the collective expression must surely be....

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Viewed from the perspective of other languages such as German (cf. "Tageszeit"), daytime would seem to be an appropriate word. Alas, daytime has a different meaning in English, leaving you with "time of day".

Comment: There isn't a single word but a phrase: [time of day](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20of%20day). You can try the hyphenated form: time-of-day.

Comment: Are you looking for the name of the group of words that contains "morning", "afternoon", etc... I know those as parts of the day. So maybe daypart (mentioned above by Dan Bron) could be adopted for this use?

Answer (score 1):

If you just use the word *time* it should pretty much cover what you are looking for.

Comment: Not in the example given, no. “Insert the correct time to greet someone at 11 AM” makes no sense at all—the only possible answer the person doing the test (whatever exactly it is) would be able to guess at would be “11 AM”, since that is the only possible time to greet someone at 11 AM.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's because the instruction is badly worded. These greetings are really idioms, and it always make sense to label their individual words. The instruction should say something like "Give the complete greeting appropriate for 11AM"

Comment: Obviously the example is badly worded, I just used it to provide a context for the word I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other word in colloquial American English in general use besides mid-morning or morning for 11:00 a.m. But you would never say, Good Mid-morning. Good morning is typically reserved for first thing in the morning, say up to 10:00 a.m., depending on regional habits. Good day works well for 11:00 a.m. There is Good afternoon, Good evening, and good night, but those are the time of day ranges in typical use, few beyond those without sounding unusual.

Answer (score -2):

If there can be an [*evil hour*](https://archive.org/stream/englishidioms00dixouoft#page/126/mode/2up/search/hour), an [*early hour*](https://archive.org/stream/englishidioms00dixouoft#page/126/mode/2up/search/hour), or even an [*eleventh hour*](https://archive.org/stream/englishidioms00dixouoft#page/126/mode/2up/search/hour) -- then there surely must also be a "***Good hour***!" at our disposal.

In case someone would rather say "hour" (in an fit of exactitude, precision, or specificity) instead of "morning", "afternoon", or "evening".

And in fact James Main Dixon did list "to keep [**good hours**](https://archive.org/stream/englishidioms00dixouoft#page/126/mode/2up/search/hour)" among his *English Idioms*. Of course, the meaning has changed a little in over a century.