# Hypernym for different time sections of a day

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

In a day, we have different names for different times of it. For example, *morning, afternoon, night, evening, noon*.

I need a hypernym for them all. What word should I use?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/97129/14666   http://english.stackexchange.com/q/101796/14666  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/192328/14666

Comment: Please search previous posts first. Of course, they may not have an answer acceptable/ suitable for you, but still.

Comment: May have to settle for "part of day" to be precise. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Parts_of_a_day

Comment: (Remotely) related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28498/precise-names-for-parts-of-a-day

Comment: @Kris, of course I've searched before. But the question is, how would you search, when you don't know the keyword(s)? That was a little unfair in my opinion.

Comment: Saeed, didn't I? :)

Comment: Yeah, you did. However, you should both look at your score, and at the same time it seems that you're a native English speaker. Those things affect the search. I did search for what I wanted, and of course I searched Google before SE, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Saeed, It's just that someone wanting to post a question is required, or at least expected, to check first. Good Luck, anyway.

Comment: Has been asked several times already.

Answer (score 5):

The hypernym for the different times of day is, rather unsurprisingly, [*time of day*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/time_of_day):

> **Hyponyms**
>
> dawn, morning, noon/midday, afternoon, evening, dusk, night, midnight (Category: [en:Times of day](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:en:Times_of_day))

And nobody at all calls them *day periods* or *day sections*.

Comment: Please see my comment at OP.

Comment: Just kidding, could *mid-night* be a "time of day"?

Answer (score 1):

What about **day period**?

With [period from wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/period) :

> -
>   an extent of time meaningful in the life of a person, in history, etc.
>
> -
>   a round of time marked by some repeating event or action
>
> -
>   any of the parts into which something, as a school day, etc., is divided

Comment: Well, it's still far from being a good name. However, it's useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although I doubt it's standard, we have often used the term *day parts*, for example when creating separate faces for an animated clock, we'd place them all in a folder called **/dayparts**

Comment: The radio industry uses daypart extensively.