# What's the -nym for describing a time of day or a period of time?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, time

We have these...

- **Morning**, **afternoon**, **evening**, **night**, **day**, and it's like **night and day**
- **Midnight** and **noon**, and **high noon**
- **Yesterday**, **today**, and **tomorrow**
- **Earlier**, **later**, and **now**
- **Four O'Clock**
- **2300 hours**
- **Yesteryear**
- **October**, **Wednesday**, **1982**
- **The Age of Wonder**, **The Pleistocene Era**
- **Once upon a time**, **never**, **forever**, **forever and a day**
- *You get the idea...*

Is there a word for named moments or periods of time—one of the `-nym` suffixed words? I did a search and can't seem to find a word in reasonably wide usage.

This [Q&A](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192328/single-word-for-time-of-the-day) doesn't address my question (completely). A search on a term that made sense to me in the family of Latin-derived terms like demonym (which is [fully documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym)) and [retronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retronym) is **temponym**, which has been coined in [technical circles](https://www.bing.com/search?q=temponym&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN).

At the least, it doesn't seem to have a dictionary definition yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word **chrononym** is suitable.

> Etymology
>   A 1979: chrono- +‎ -onym.
>   Noun
>   chrononym (plural chrononyms)
>
> (semiotics) A term for a specific period of time, such as "summer" or "week."

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chrononym)

[Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/chrononym)

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/chrononym)

[Smart Dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/chrononym)

Comment: Well, duh. That is so obvious now that you pointed it out. Thank you.